# I'm having a hard time understanding why my function is returning earlier than expected (async await)

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm not exactly sure what's happening or maybe my understanding of asynchronous functions is just bad.

I have two functions:

```
const retrieveConvosList=(username)=>{
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        await userModel.findOne({username:username},async(error,foundUser)=>{
            if(error) return reject(error);
            resolve(await retrieveConvosListName(foundUser.convos,username));
        })
    })
}
```

and

```
const retrieveConvosListName=async(convoIDList,username)=>{
    let convoListAndName = [];
    convoIDList.forEach(async(convo)=> {
        await messages.findById(convo,(error,foundConvo)=>{
            if(error) console.log(error);
            foundConvo.users.forEach(user => {
                if(user != username){
                    const convoIndex = foundConvo.convoIndex;
                    const objLit = {};
                    objLit[convoIndex] = user;
                    convoListAndName.push(objLit);
                }
            });
        })
    });
    return convoListAndName;
})
```

**retrieveConvosList** is called in one of my routes like this

```
renderOBJ.convoList = await roomUtilLib.retrieveConvosList(renderOBJ.user.username);
```

The problem is that my function **retrieveConvosListName** is returning the value of **convoListAndName** (which is an empty array that I assigned at the start of the function) before my callback of **messages.findById** completes.

I can't seem to understand it's behavior.